# is there some arbitrage relation one can show between a short term vanilla , a cliquet , and a long term vanilla?

Tags: arbitrage

suppose all 3 are calls and have same strike moneyness.

The cliquet (V12) pays off S2-S1-K12

The short vanilla (V1) pays S1-K1

The long vanilla (V2) pays S2-K2.

All are floored at zero ofcourse.

K1,K2 , and K12 have some relationship eg K12 = K2-K1 with all of them having same moneyness

Is it possible to demonstrate that V1+V12 > V2 ? (talking about spot premiums here). (if it helps to assume zero interest rates we can do that).

I would think that essentially, in V2 your underlying and your strike is the sum of those of V1 and V12 , and so V2 is like a basket option , and we know that a basket is less than the sum of vanillas because correlation cannot be above 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(A-B)+ >= (A)+  -  (B)+$

where $A$ and $B$ are the vanilla option payoffs. This is a mathematical identity that only uses convexity of the $+$ function.

Comment: Ofcourse i forgot this, thanks!.  Ps why did you use -B?

Comment: Minus is the mathematical operation whereas plus is used in usual notion of the max compared to 0.

Comment: yes that is clear! my q is just, why did you not write (A+B)+ <= A+  +   B+  ?

Comment: I don't remember the relationship by heart or if any convention people may write it in